# added new video file is removed when simulator is relaunched

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite, xcode7.2

I am facing a problem.My Environment is:

```
OSX 10.10.5 YOsemite
xocde 7.2
```

I want to add a new video file(.mp4) in my ios simulator. i add this in

```
 /Users/mynane/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/mydevice/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

after adding this, when i relaunch my simulator, than the added video is not shown. It shows only the previously added default images.

I also delete

```
 photoData
```

but same result.

how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste you video file or any file which you want to preload with ios simulator in below path

```
String str = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/SampleContent/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/
```

or you can use  below java code which will copy your desired file into the simuator location.

```
  public  void preloadFiletoSimulator(String filename){
    try {
        File dest = new File(str);
        String name = AppConstant.RESOURCE_DIR+filename;
        File source = new File(name);
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```